# deploy nextjs with output: 'standalone' in nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js, deployment

currently using route handler in app router.
export: 'static' does not support route handler request so have to use output: 'standalone' instead.

tried in nginx.conf:

```
location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  try_files $uri $uri.html;
  @next.js
  @public
}                    
location @nextjs {
  proxy_pass SERVER_NAME;
}
```